# Easier way to calculate the expected value of $p^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, momentum

I was doing some math with some wave functions when I stumbled upon this one:

\begin{equation}
\phi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2 a^3}{\pi}} \frac{1}{a^2 + x^2} \mathrm{e}^{i k_0 x}
\end{equation}

I wanted to calculate the uncertainty in the momentum so I changed to $p$-representation obtaining
$$\psi(p) = \sqrt{\frac{a}{\hbar}}\,\pi\,\exp \left(-\left|a \left(\frac{p}{h} - k_0\right)\right|\right),$$
but I don't know how to compute $\langle p^2\rangle$ correctly because if I use $p$-representation, I obtain big integrals but if I use $x$-representation, while computing $\langle p\rangle$ is very easy, the calculations for $\langle p^2\rangle$ are kind of complex.

I was wondering if there was another way to calculate this expected value without it involving annoying integrals.

Comment: The integrals you get in the momentum representation don't look that bad to me. You may want to look up the $\Gamma$[-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: Your denominator of *p* is most probably an ℏ. Absorb *a/ℏ*  into *p* with extreme prejudice. Then shift *p* so the exponent is symmetric at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change to p-representation. Just use the fact that p = hbar/i * d/dx and do the math. And your p-representation wavefunction is just an exponential (apart from the absolute value). Use the gamma function (it is really easy).